# What does a "?" mean in Common Product Enumeration (CPE)?

Tags: standards, vulnerability-management

I looked at the documentation for cpe Naming Specification Version 2.3

http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistir/ir7695/NISTIR-7695-CPE-Naming.pdf

Specification says, "*" or "-" is explained as "ANY" or "NA". (6.1.2.2 Summary of algorithm)

But the "?" is simply a special character that can be handled by other CPE specifications.  It appears that "?", "??" can be used (5.3.2 Restrictions on attribute-value strings).

I wonder if this has the same meaning as regular expressions.
Then I wonder why they didn't write that down in the specification document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from its use in the document, it is clear that both * and ? are used in their regular expression meanings.

My guess as to why they do not explicitly say this is that the use in this way is not a part of this spec, which is why they say it is for "other" specifications (i.e. regex and similar parsing schemes).